# javascript auto-upload or reading a file form a local dir

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, file-upload, filereader, local-files

I tried to read a local file. I've got a solution for MSIE.
But chorme and firefox are a little bit more restrict for such manipulations.

So I tried to use the FileReader but it seems taht it is not possible to read form a local dirve.

After some tests I've got this idea.
I want to 'auto-upload' the file without any dialog.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<script>
function handle_files(files) {
  for (i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
    file = files[i]
    console.log(file)
    var reader = new FileReader()
    reader.onload = function(e) {
      console.log(e.target.result)
    }
    reader.onerror = function(stuff) {
      console.log("error", stuff)
      console.log (stuff.getMessage())
    }
    reader.readAsText(file) //readAsdataURL
  }

}

handle_files(document.getElementById("input").value);
</script>
<body>
FileReader that works!
<input type="file" multiple onmouseover="handle_files(this.files)" id="input" value="K:\\somewhere\\over\\the\\rainbow\\c_comments.txt">
</body>
</html>
```

My question is now: How to manage a quite upload ?
Maybe somebody has a nice idea.
Thanks

br

Markus